# Convert timestamp to normal date in JSON

Tags: json, date, timestamp

Following is the date stored in the database:

```
2014-05-23 13:34:32
```

The date column is a timestamp, and the value returned in the JSON object is:

```
 1390421072000
```

When I try to convert this back to a date with the following it gives a wrong date - `2014-01-22T20:04:34.000Z`:

```
log.logDateTime  = new Date(log.logDateTime);
```

I guess this has something to do with the format or locale, in that case how do I do the correct conversion? I want to get the date as it is in the DB.

In server side, I do a conversion as follows:

```
df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date logDate = (Date) df.parseObject(df.format(lg.getTime()));
```

Comment: `1390421072000ms` from `1970-01-01 00:00:00` = `Wed Jan 22 20:04:32 UTC 2014`. Is there some conversion etc. in between that could cause the problem?

Comment: Updated the question with some server side formatting i'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dateformat is incorrect. It should be:

```
df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

The `mm` stands for minutes, `MM` for months. Additionally you want to use `HH` which stands for 24h time.

Comment: thanks, this halfway solved my problem. But still the date is displayed as 2014-05-23T08:04:32.000Z. How do I format it to show as 2014-05-23 13:34:32?

Comment: In Javascript? There's no out-of-the-box way, but the question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date

Comment: Yes.. the time is incorrect because you're using `hh`, use `HH`.